# Error while deleting internet explorer

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer, uninstall

My Internet Explorer is not visible in the uninstall programs list but and when I try to remove the folder from c drive it shows the error

> You require permission from TrustedInstaller to make changes to this folder

Because of this I am not even able to install a new version of Internet explorer. So please tell how to remove Internet explorer from the system. I am using Windows 7.

Comment: you don't need to remove IE to upgrade it. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: actually i want to install internet explorer 11 but as soon as i try to install it ,it shows that higher version of this is already installed,so am not able to install a new version.Aso when i try to remove this i get an error ,and i want to know the reason why actually this program is not shown as an option in uninstall programs list.

Comment: You may want to run sfc /scannow, as you may have corrupted your system by deleting system files.

Answer (score 1):

You can find (and uninstall) Internet Explorer installations in:
**Control Panel>Programs and Features>Installed Updates**
You can highlight it by selecting a random update and hitting **I**

Comment: thanku so much sir,its working now but i wanted to know the reason why dont we have a permission to delete internet explorer and why after i there was a need to uninstall the updates of explorer,and even after uninstalling it,when i run my exe file of internet explorer 11 ,it again still shows the error that a higher version of this is already installed so sir can u tell the reason for this,although when i opened my internet explorer it showed that "YOUR BROWSER HAS BEEN UPGRADED"

Comment: It is never a good idea to delete program files. When a program is installed, it also adds registry keys. Only by uninstalling you will also remove the registry keys needed, keeping it clean and avoiding corruption. To check the version of Internet Explorer press Alt-X, A after opening it, or search for "About Internet Explorer" under "Tools". Sometimes an installation can go wrong, and therefore you need to uninstall and reinstall a program for it to work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Internet Explorer came bundled with Windows. This means that when you install Windows it install a version of IE and that (first) version is not uninstallable. All you can do is uninstall the updates you installed.

Read [THIS](http://helpdeskgeek.com/windows-7/windows-7-how-to-delete-files-protected-by-trustedinstaller/) article to know how to delete files protected by Trusted Installer

To forcefully uninstall a software install Revo Uninstaller or a similar program.